# Timeout for android background services in API level 26

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

Android Oreo introduced new  limitations to background services.
The [doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) states

> "While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of **several minutes** in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle."

(emphasis added by me)

How long is "**several minutes**"?

Comment: At least not long enough for the service to run forever in the background. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have an app running in self-made kiosk mode that needs to be restarted when it crashes (plus other services required for it that need to be restarted if they fail). It needs to work on android 5, too

Comment: And I'm mainly interested in what the timeframe is

Answer (score 0):

Define your app as a Launcher and replace the default launcher (deactivate it) of the device. The launcher will be automatically relaunched by the system if it crashes. As the launcher is gonna be your app, it will be automatically restarted

Add in your Manifest (as [explained here](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/)):

> ```
> <intent-filter>
>   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>   <!-- The following two intent-filters are the key to set homescreen -->
>   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
>   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>
> </intent-filter>
> ```

Comment: So you don't need to have a service running in the background.

Comment: I already did that. I am trying to add additional measurements to keep things running and automated. Plus I wanted to find out the timeframe for "several minutes" regardless of a solution to the problem

Comment: "Several minutes" means the app has enough time to complete anything necessary before the system stops the services and everything. So how long is "several minutes" doesn't really matter. The only thing you need to know is that your services are going to be stopped at some point when the app is in the background. So your implementation needs to take this is consideration.

Comment: So i could keep monitoring the health of the app itself and restart it if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using volley library for call API then you have to add below code

```
   int socketTimeout = 30000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    request.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    APIController.getInstance(context).addRequest(request, TAG);
```

Comment: How is this relevant?